# implementing __next__() in python linked list

Tags: python, iterator

I would like to retrieve a particular node in a linked list by iterating a specified number of times; for example, to retrieve the 4th node. By implementing `__iter__()`, I can iterate with a for loop, but I don't know how get a `next()` function to work. I've commented out my attempt at a `next()` function; when it is left in, I still get  `AttributeError: 'LinkedList' object has no attribute 'next'`

**EDIT:** I would like the `getNode(self, loc)` to return a node at the specified location by calling `next()` if possible.

Here is the Node and LinkedList classes:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,  data = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.data)
        
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, nodes = None):
        self.head = None
        if nodes is not None:
            node = Node(data=nodes.pop(0))
            self.head = node
            for elem in nodes:
                node.next = Node(data=elem)
                node = node.next
        
    def __repr__(self):
        node = self.head
        nodes = []
        while node is not None:
            nodes.append(str(node.data))
            node = node.next
        nodes.append("None")
        return " -> ".join(nodes)
    
    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            yield node
            node = node.next
    
    # def __next__(self):
    #     return self.next
    

    def getNode(self,loc):
        cnt = 0
        for i in self:
            if cnt < loc:
                cnt += 1
            else:
                break 
        return i
            
        
ll = LinkedList([1,2,3,4,5])
print(ll)
print(ll.getNode(3))

for i in range(3):
    print(ll.next())
```

[OUTPUT]
I
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> None
4
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/Users/jk/_python_source/misc_python/_mymisc/Leetcode work/LinkedList.py", line 53, in <module>
    print(ll.next())

AttributeError: 'LinkedList' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Comment: Get an iterator with `i = iter(ll)` and call `next()` on that. This is basically what is happening when you iterate with a for loop.

Comment: Since you're using a generator, *your* class shouldn't have a `__next__`, the builtin generator class does.

Comment: When I try that in the getNode() method as
        for i in range(loc):
            it.next()
 I get: AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: Don't use `it.next()`, use `next(it)`. You're probably following tutorials from an ancient version of Python.

Comment: next(it) is not working either: def getNode(self,loc):
        it = iter(self)
        for i in range(loc):
            next(it)
        return i

Comment: Your Linked List class *should not implement `__next__`*, containers aren't iterators, they are iterables

Comment: That is the distinction I did not fully understand (iterators vs iterables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing way more work than you have to. Once you've implemented `__iter__`, the rest falls into place. You can use it to implement pretty much all your other functions, like `get_node`, `__str__` or `__repr__`, etc.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)


class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self, value):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(value)
        else:
            for cursor in self:
                pass
            cursor.next = Node(value)
        return self

    def get_node(self, node_index):
        for index, node in enumerate(self):
            if index == node_index:
                break
        else:
            return None
        return node

    def __str__(self):
        return " -> ".join(map(str, self))

    def __iter__(self):
        cursor = self.head
        while cursor is not None:
            yield cursor
            cursor = cursor.next

ll = LinkedList().add(1).add(2).add(3)
print(ll)

for node_index in 0, 1, 2, 3:
    print("The node at index {} is {}".format(node_index, ll.get_node(node_index)))
```

Output:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3
The node at index 0 is 1
The node at index 1 is 2
The node at index 2 is 3
The node at index 3 is None
>>>
```

Comment: This is a great example of an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The OP says they want to use `next()`, but really they just want to implement `get_node` and think they need `next()` so they ask about their solution rather than what they are actually trying to solve.

Comment: No, I wouldn't say next() was irrelevant; it ultimately was what I wanted, but I did not think I was going to get an answer that had it, so I took the next best thing (so to speak)

Answer (score 0):

This`getNode()`also works:

```
def getNode(self,loc):
    it = iter(self)
    for i in range(loc):
        next(it)
    return next(it)
```